# Python + Django: Weird memory leaks with Database Queries

Tags: python, django, database, memory-leaks

I wrote a routine that browses through a bunch of files and adds database entries (if not already present) according to the data, found in each line of those files.

```
for root, dirs, files in walk_dir(path):
    for file_name in files:
        file_path = join_path(root, file_name)
        with transaction.commit_on_success():
            with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                for i, line in enumerate(f):
                    handle_line(line)

def handle_line(line):
    phrase, translated_phrase, context = get_params(line)

    try:
        ph = Phrase.objects.get(name=phrase)
    except Phrase.DoesNotExist:
        ph = Phrase(name=phrase)
        ph.save()

    try:
        tr = Translation.object.get(phrase=ph, name=translated_phrase)
    except Translation.DoesNotExist:
        tr = Translation(phrase=ph, name=translated_phrase)
        tr.save()

    try:
        tm = TMTranslation.object.get(translation=tr, context=context)
    except TMTranslation.DoesNotExist:
        tm = TMTranslation(translation=tr, context=context)
        tm.save()
```

There might be a lot of data to be processed (maybe 1000 files with several 1000 lines in each file). But still, I don't see why I'm always running into memory problems. Shouldn't memory be freed at least after each file (after each transaction)?

But what I am experiencing is that this process will slowly eat up all my memory and will start using up the swap space as well. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set `DEBUG = False`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I actually did, yes.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have to correct myself. I was using `DEBUG = True`. Switching to `DEBUG = False` seems to have solved it. What is the reason behind that?

Comment: This used to be a FAQ: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory although it seems like the query log is now bounded at 9000 since version 1.7.